# How to open external links in new window?

Tags: 7, navigation

I'm using the "filtered HTML" text format in the node body with the "convert URLs into links" option enabled.
I would like to have all external links open in a new window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [External Links](http://drupal.org/project/extlink) module does exactly that:

> External Links is a small module used to differentiate between internal and external links. Using jQuery, it will find all external links on a page and add an external icon indicating it will take you offsite or a mail icon for mailto: links.
>
> Configuration options:
>
> - Apply icons to either mailto: or external links or both.
> - **Configure external links to open in a new window.**
> - A confirmation message when leaving the site.
> - Regular expression inclusion and exclusion of links considered external.
> - CSS selector inclusion and exclusion of elements for processing

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use JavaScript for this, you need to implement [`theme_link(&variables)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_link/7) in your template.php file.

Test `$variables['path']` for [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) declaration at the beginning. If there is none, leave it be. If there is some, add target to attributes:

```
$variables['options']['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
```

Of course it bases on assumption that your HTML version supports `target` attribute, but this version is also theme-dependent, and most browsers will respect it even if technically it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Linkit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit) and add a "target" attribute at admin/config/content/linkit/manage/default/attributes/add

It has two options:

- Selectlist with predefined targets.

[image: Dialog with options]

- Simple checkbox to allow links to be opened in a new browser window or tab.

[image: Dialog with checkbox]